# Not able to run my program in Firefox through selenium web driver

Tags: java, automated-tests

Whenever I try to run my program through firefox browser, by default skype extensions gets launch and get this error in console..

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

Please help me out for this

```
package practice;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class makemytrip {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/") ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing/disabling any Skype extension which is installed in Firefox. 
If issue still persists, try searching for "Skype click to call" extension and un-install in from Control panel.

Hope this works for you!!